# Create UDF ISO file with .NET DiscUtils

Tags: c#

I have Bluray folder structure

```
- BMDV
- ANY!
- FAB!
...
```

I use library https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils and I tried:

```
CDBuilder builder = new CDBuilder();
builder.UseJoliet = false;

AddDir("paths", builder, "paths");

builder.Build("stuff.iso");


static void AddDir(string dirPath, CDBuilder builder, string originalPath)
{
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath);
  var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath);
  var pathDiff = string.Join(separator, dirPath.Split(separator).Except(originalPath.Split(separator)));

  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathDiff))
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Adding directory {pathDiff}");
    builder.AddDirectory(pathDiff);
  }

  foreach (var file in files)
  {
    string location = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathDiff) ?
       Path.GetFileName(file) :
       $"{pathDiff}{separator}{Path.GetFileName(file)}";

    Console.WriteLine($"Adding file: {location}");
    builder.AddFile(location, file);
  }

  foreach (var dir in dirs)
  {
    AddDir(dir, builder, originalPath);
  }
}
```

When open ISO with BDInfo (https://www.videohelp.com/software/BDInfo), it says that is not valid UDF stream.

How to create UDF ISO file ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the DiscUtils library does not support creating UDF images at the moment. It only supports reading.